# A place in the autocomplete dropdown doesn't have a place id

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I found a place in the google places javascript autocomplete dropdown that doesn't have a place id. Is it normal for places to not have a place id? How can you do anything with the place if it doesn't have an id? As an example, try typing "valve corporation" into the autocomplete dropdown here at this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder and pressing enter. It won't give you the place id. Try typing any other random place and it will tell you the place id. I tried it in my own dropdown and the object returned by the autocomplete doesn't have a property called `place_id`. If I try to use it, I get `undefined`

Comment: Use the coordinates instead and also you'll notice that it also doesn't take the map to the place meaning it can't find the place id because it can't find the place it knows it exists but it can't find it

Comment: This would probably be the result of Google knowing there is a company there but not having a geographical location for it.